# How to render two copies of a complex shape in kineticjs

Tags: kineticjs, layer

**How to place two instances of a group side-by-side?**

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
      container: 'canvas',
      height: 125,
      width: 250         
 });

 var layerLeft = new Kinetic.Layer({
     x: 62.5,
     y: 62.5,
     height: 125,
     width: 125          
 });

var layerRight = new Kinetic.Layer({
     x: 187.5,
     y: 62.5,
     height: 125,
     width: 125          
 });

 var group = new Kinetic.Group({
     offset:   [62.5, 62.5]           
 });


    var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({

      x: (stage.getWidth() / 4),
      y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
      width: 124,
      height: 124,
      stroke: 'grey',
      strokeWidth: 1
    });

    var topPath = new Kinetic.Path({         
      data: 'M50.5,10.5 L50.5,10.5 75,10.5 L75,10.5 68.55,34.5 L68.55,34.5 56.45,34.5 L56.45,34.5 50.5,10.5 Z',
      stroke: 'grey',
      strokeWidth: 1          
    });

    var leftPath = new Kinetic.Path({ 
      data: 'M25,100 L25,100 42,81 L42,81 35.5,70.5 L35.5,70.5 11,77 L11,77 25,100 Z',
      stroke: 'grey',
      strokeWidth: 1          
    });

    var rightPath = new Kinetic.Path({          
      data: 'M100,100 L100,100 83,81 L83,81 89.5,70.5 L89.5,70.5 113.5,76.75 L113.5,76.75  100,100 Z',
      stroke: 'grey',
      strokeWidth: 1
    });

      group.add(circle);
      group.add(topPath);
      group.add(leftPath);
      group.add(rightPath);
      layerRight.add(group);
      //layerLeft.add(group); 
      stage.add(layerLeft);
      stage.add(layerRight);
```

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvGvH/11/)

*Things I've tried:*

• adding the paths/circles to two separate groups on one layer.

• adding one group onto two layers.

Is this a closure problem? I've read all about it, but I don't quite understand how to address it.

Comment: can you explain a bit further on what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Chris Graff, are you trying to duplicate the circle ? Do you want two circles side by side? If so I think you have misunderstood what groups are for.

Comment: @EricRowell Tape reels! http://jsfiddle.net/cvGvH/17/

Answer (score 1):

This is a little hard for me to explain (and I could even be wrong;) ) but Ill give it a shot.

When you create a group it refrences the items in it not create new ones and then alters the attributes of them according to its attributes.
So if you had a circle of x=0 but the groups x=20 then the circle will get drawn at 20....it does not create a new circle and put its x as 20.
So if you had two groups both refrencing the same circle then the one that comes last is where the circle will be.
Group one says circleX=20, but Group2 says circleX=40 so it will draw that circle (as their is only one) at 40.
So when you clone a group your only cloning information that says where to draw the circle, not creating another circle aswell as the information as to where to put it, only the information of where to put it.

You can deal with this by explicitly creating two circles and putting them in their own groups.
In your case it would look like this....

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'canvas',
    height: 125,
    width: 250
});

var layerLeft = new Kinetic.Layer({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    height: 125,
    width: 125
});

var layerRight = new Kinetic.Layer({
    x: 125,
    y: 0,
    height: 125,
    width: 125
});



function createThing() {
    var group = new Kinetic.Group();

    var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({

        x: (stage.getWidth() / 4),
        y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
        width: 124,
        height: 124,
        stroke: 'grey',
        strokeWidth: 1
    });

    var topPath = new Kinetic.Path({
        data: 'M50.5,10.5 L50.5,10.5 75,10.5 L75,10.5 68.55,34.5 L68.55,34.5 56.45,34.5 L56.45,34.5 50.5,10.5 Z',
        stroke: 'grey',
        strokeWidth: 1
    });

    var leftPath = new Kinetic.Path({
        data: 'M25,100 L25,100 42,81 L42,81 35.5,70.5 L35.5,70.5 11,77 L11,77 25,100 Z',
        stroke: 'grey',
        strokeWidth: 1
    });

    var rightPath = new Kinetic.Path({
        data: 'M100,100 L100,100 83,81 L83,81 89.5,70.5 L89.5,70.5 113.5,76.75 L113.5,76.75  100,100 Z',
        stroke: 'grey',
        strokeWidth: 1
    });
    group.add(circle);
    group.add(topPath);
    group.add(leftPath);
    group.add(rightPath);
    return group;
}

var group1 = createThing();
var group2 = createThing();

layerRight.add(group1);
layerLeft.add(group2);

stage.add(layerLeft);
stage.add(layerRight);
```

​http://jsfiddle.net/cvGvH/12/

If anyone can explain that better, feel free to edit this post or make another answer.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much! My groups/layers were being overwritten.  Using the Group constructor in the context of a function prevents this because of closure?  Just want to make sure I understand correctly.

Comment: @ChrisGraff Nah not closures....um...I explained it as best I could in the answer, sorry if its not clear enough.